# losing cookie when going from page to page

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I seem to be losing the cookie information when going from page to page.

I have the generation of a cookie in a header.php file, which is then included on other pages. If i refresh one page the cookie does create a new one. However, when i go to a new page a new cookie is generated.

I have getCookie() in my header and then using $cookieID in the rest of the site when i need to use it.

here is the function im using to check if a cookie already exisits and if not generate the cookie

```
function getCookie() {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ID'])){
        $cookieID = $_COOKIE['ID'];
    }
    else{
        //generate random value for cookie id
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $uuid =  substr($charid, 0, 8)
                 .substr($charid,20,12);

        setcookie( "ID", $uuid, time()+604800 ); // 7 days
        $cookieID = $_COOKIE['ID'];
            //need to refresh the page to get the new cookie ID
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0'>  ";
    }
    return $cookieID;
}
```

Comment: In the else statement, wouldn't you need to set `$cookieID` to be equal to `$uuid`? Isn't `$_COOKIE['ID']` not set at that point?

Comment: You might want to consider what your code does for users with cookies disabled - depending on where this function is called they may get stuck in an infinite refresh loop.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the path parameter in the `setcookie()` call, to, for example `/`, if your site isn't in some subdirectory:

```
setcookie('ID', $uuid, time() + 604900, '/');
```

Also take care to use the same domain name everywhere for your site, otherwise some confusion may arise when a cookie set for, say, www.example.com is not availabe on `example.com` without the *www* subdomain.

Comment: Great! i had the site in a subdirectory this has resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the following;

```
setcookie( "ID", $uuid, time()+604800, '/');
```

This sets the domain to root, so should work for your whole website.

Also, if you set a cookie on example.com -  it automatically carries over to sub1.example.com, www.example.com etc but unfortunately this doesn't work in reverse.

Comment: Great! i had the site in a subdirectory this has resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be your issue, but make sure your domain is not changing in any way when you nav through your app.

For example, going from http://www.yourpage.com/page1 to http://yourpage.com/page2 would lose your cookies, because you dropped the www.